# Using custom Debug Keys in Intellij IDEA 10 Community Ed

Tags: android, intellij-idea

So for the past 2 days I've been using IntelliJ IDEA 10 community edition for evaluation and am Already too comfortable with it to go back to Eclipse. However, there's a problem that's a deal breaker for my small team: We use Facebook integration and in order to use the APIs we need to sign with the same debug key as what's registered on Facebook.
Using the same key also makes swapping devices easier as you don't have to uninstall the project every time you swap.

And now ... my 'question' ... Can I use a custom Android debug key with Intellij IDEA?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IDEA is using [debug keys from the standard location](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html#debugmode):

> The default storage location for AVDs
>   is in ~/.android/ on OS X and Linux,
>   in C:\Documents and
>   Settings\.android\ on Windows
>   XP, and in C:\Users\.android\
>   on Windows Vista and Windows 7.

The file you need is located there and is called **debug.keystore**. So just replace it with another one with the required debug keys.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm already doing that. I was hoping it would offer a method similar to eclipse so that I can point it to the debug key that is checked in with the project for the sake of workflow and new user setup.

Answer (score 9):

FYI: It seems that this was not in IntelliJ IDEA, but CazyCoder filed a support issue (thanks) and it was marked as "Fix Version: XI" earlier today.

So the next release (IDEA 11) should have this fix.

Comment: This has indeed been added in IDEA 11, but it's a non-obvious (at least to me) place to configure it.  Project Structure -> Facets -> Click on an Android Facet -> "Compiler" tab -> Custom debug keystore.

Comment: Thanks, @Eric! I was starting to think they kind of forgot that feature.